# How To Add data-plugin-datepicker tag into MVC @Html.EditorFor

Tags: model-view-controller

I was new to MVC and I have a date field wanted to add calendar popup for user to select.I got below sample code which work in my View. But I not able to figure out how to add the tag into my razor field (@Html.EditorFor). I really need help on this. Thanks in advance.

```
<div class="input-group">
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
    </span>
    <input type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control">
</div> 

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control"}, new { @id="data-plugin-datepicker" } })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that I can use the input code directly and just adding additional id & name attributes to the code like below code. Hopefully later can help someone on this. Thank you everyone.

```
<input type="text" data-plugin-datepicker class="form-control" id="myDate" name="myDate>
```